# When the recognition classes are increased from 11 to 17, the convolutional neural network returns Value Error. Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

There were 11 classes in total ['.', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']. The code works.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from IPython.display import Image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np


# Directory with training data
train_dir = 'train'
# Folder with data to check
val_dir = 'val'
# The data directory for testing
test_dir = 'test'
# Image size
img_width, img_height = 56, 56
# Image-based tensor dimension for input data to the neural network
# backend Tensorflow, channel_last
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
# Number of epochs
epochs = 40
# Mini-sample size
batch_size = 32
# Number of images for training
nb_train_samples = 7700
# Number of images to check
nb_validation_samples = 1650
# Number of images to test
nb_test_samples = 1650

'''creating a convolutional neural network'''
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(11))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


'''Compiling a neural network'''
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

'''Writing the model to files:'''
callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint('saved_models/model-dense-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.5f}-{val_accuracy:.4f}.hdf5')]

'''Creating an image generator'''
ImageDataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

'''Data generator for training based on images from the catalog'''
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

val_generator = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

test_generator = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')


'''Training the model using generators'''
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    callbacks=callbacks)

'''Evaluating the quality of the network using a generator on a test sample'''
scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)

print("Accuracy on test data: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Code with 17 classes

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from IPython.display import Image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np


# Directory with training data
train_dir = 'train'
# Folder with data to check
val_dir = 'val'
# The data directory for testing
test_dir = 'test'
# Image size
img_width, img_height = 45, 45
# Image-based tensor dimension for input data to the neural network
# backend Tensorflow, channel_last
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
# Number of epochs
epochs = 40
# Mini-sample size
batch_size = 32
# Number of images for training
nb_train_samples = 16320
# Number of images to check
nb_validation_samples = 2040
# Number of images to test
nb_test_samples = 2040

'''creating a convolutional neural network'''
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(17))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


'''Compiling a neural network'''
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

'''Writing the model to files:'''
callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint('saved_models/model-dense-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.5f}-{val_accuracy:.4f}.hdf5')]

'''Creating an image generator'''
ImageDataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

'''Data generator for training based on images from the catalog'''
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

val_generator = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

test_generator = ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')


'''Training the model using generators'''
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    callbacks=callbacks)

'''Evaluating the quality of the network using a generator on a test sample'''
scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)

print("Accuracy on test data: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

*ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d_3/MaxPool}} = MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]' with input shapes: [?,1,1,128].*

Comment: How many classes are there in the test/train images?

Comment: You have decreased the image size (image height and width), that's why the error occurs. Either increase the image height and width or reduce the model size in the 2nd case to solve the error.

Comment: Its not the number of classes, you also changed the input shape from 56x56 to 45x45, which is the real source of the problem

Comment: Each data set: test training and value has the same number of classes.

Comment: In code with 17 classes, images are prepared 45x45 px. And in the code of 11 classes 56x56 px. That's why the dimensions are such.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the depth of the problem, but when reducing the size (padding='same') of the code-earned.

```
# Directory with training data
train_dir = 'train'
# Folder with data to check
val_dir = 'val'
# The data directory for testing
test_dir = 'test'
# Image size
img_width, img_height = 45, 45
# Image-based tensor dimension for input data to the neural network
# backend Tensorflow, channel_last
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
# Number of epochs
epochs = 40
# Mini-sample size
batch_size = 32
# Number of images for training
nb_train_samples = 16320
# Number of images to check
nb_validation_samples = 2040
# Number of images to test
nb_test_samples = 2040

'''creating a convolutional neural network'''
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(17))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```